# TeX.SE data explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed

The site's data explorer is now available:

http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries

Thanks for that!

It seems to me that there's a mistake: TeX meta has been chosen instead. Both 
http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries and 
http://data.stackexchange.com/texmeta/queries should be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k ... this should be fixed now

Comment: Great, thank you!